# Cheerio get option values from select class

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to get all the values from a list of options in a select class:

```
<select class="list_items">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this in cheerio?

Answer (score 6):

```
const $ = require('cheerio')
$('.list_items').find('option').each((i,op) => {
   console.log($(op).text())
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
const $ = require('cheerio');

$(".list_items option").each(() => {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```